# How to make duplicated object be colored independently?

Tags: materials, objects

I have a blender object. I applied a diffuse color to the object. Then I duplicated it. Now I want to apply a different color to the duplicated object, however, the original object also changed to the new color.

How can I make the two objects have different colors?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a new material (you duplicated the object but you didn't make a different material).

Click the number next to the material name to make a single user copy.

[image]